# how to disable Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException

Tags: asp.net

I have read a lot about this error message.
I've learned that the most common causes for this error are

1. when the response is modifed by calls to Response.Write(), response filters, HttpModules
2. server trace is enabled.

There are some suggestions like to use a web debugger (ie. Fiddler) to get the server's response, set the `EnableEventValidation="false"` to the page that this error came up, set the cookie timeout and the likes.

My question, is there any other way to avoid this like doing something on the settings of the browser?

Answer (score 0):

What is the point in hiding the error altering the browser settings? Your end user would still get that error as you wont be able to change their browser settings.

---

The key to the answer is in your question itself. You *find out what is causing the error* and then rectify it.

Useful read: [Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException - what it is and how to avoid it](http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2007/02/26/sys-webforms-pagerequestmanagerparsererrorexception-what-it-is-and-how-to-avoid-it.aspx)

Comment: thanks! if altering the browser settings is one of the solutions, i am able to advise my end user who encountered this error. actually, that user is asking for some quick solution to not see that error anymore.

Comment: which browser? ie? try disabling script debugging http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398817.aspx